# React Native keep alive http connection

Tags: react-native, axios, fetch, keep-alive

I need to use keep-alive http connection, but there is no info about this (or i did not find :()

I tried:

1. RN fetch api with `keepalive: true` prop - it's not working
2. RN fetch api with header `Connection: keep-alive`
3. Axios (https://github.com/axios/axios/issues/1846#issuecomment-434208900), but RN environment does not support http module

Is it possible to keep http connection alive for React Native's fetch method?

Comment: Do you have a solution to this ?